# ¿Como puedo agregar una columna en un datagridview en visual 2010 a la derecha?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba

Hola espero puedan apoyarme, quisiera agregar columnas en un datagridview a la derecha, como podria hacerle, con éste codigo me las agrega por default a la izquierda.

```
Private Sub Columnas()
        Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        col.Name = "CAJAS"
        TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Insert(TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Count, col)
        Dim col2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        col2.Name = "KILOS"
        TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Insert(TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Count, col2)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma habitual de agregar columnas es

```
TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Add(col2)
```

Esto agrega la `col2` a la derecha de la última columna. Si lo que quiero es poner una columna en primer lugar, a la izquierda del todo, debería hacer

```
 TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Insert(0, col2)
```

Si quiero crearla en la posición penúltima, es decir a la izquierda de la última actual debería hacer un cálculo: `TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Count` es el número de columnas, la posición de la última columna es `TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Count - 1`.

```
TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Insert(TABLAEMPACADORES.Columns.Count-1, col2)
```

Comment: Cualquiera de los métodos que mencionaste, me agrega la columna a la izquierda

Comment: Mi datagridview es de 13 columnas, si quiero agregar más columnas, me las agrega de izquierda a derecha y quiero que me las agregue al reves de derecha a izquierda, por ejemplo tengo col1,col2 en un datagridview si quiero agregar más columnas me las agrega así col3,col4,col1,col2 pero yo quiero que aparezca de la siguiente manera col1,col2,col3,col4 de izquierda a derecha pero de la ultima posicion o ultima columna